# create a view with solid dimensions in Landscape and Portrait modes

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a search bar and want to make one pixel view below it. In Storyboard and in the Landscape mode it looks like this:

[image]

But in the Portrait mode it looks like this (my divider view has very big height):

[image]

I've tried also unsuccessfully set divider view height from my code:

```
 CGRect bounds = [_divider bounds];
    [_divider setBounds:CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x,
                                   bounds.origin.y,
                                   bounds.size.width,
                                   1)];
```

EDIT:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    DLog(@"_divider 1   %f",_divider.bounds.size.height)
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    DLog(@"_divider 2   %f",_divider.bounds.size.height)
}

_divider 1   1.000000
_divider 2   257.000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved just replacing `uiview` in Storyboard with `uiimageview`.
It seems like it's not possible to attach In Storyboard a custom small `uiview` with other UI elements.
(sounds strange - but it's actually occurs in my Xcode 4.6)

Answer (score 0):

With your view selected in the story board, goto Editor->Pin->Height. On a side note, when changing the size of views in code you will want to use the view's frame and not it bounds.